# Finding the hamiltonian path in a directed cyclic graph

Tags: graph, hamiltonian-cycle, longest-path

i want to know if there is an algorithm to find the longest cyclic path in a directed weighted graph (i think this i a problem of finding the largest Hamiltonian sub-graph).

I need to start from one vertex and return to the same vertex, whit the most possible nodes traversed.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the most possible nodes, or the highest path weight?

Comment: Sorry, i would like the most possible nodes, although i am interested in a solution with the highest path weight

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a special case of the optimal euler circuit problem where all edge weights are 1; the original problem is NP-complete. Moreover, this problem can be used to solve the Hamiltonian Graph problem (a Hamiltonian cycle exists if and only if the optimal circuit traverses all nodes), so it remains NP-complete even with the special case restriction. Any exact solution will (unless P = NP) require exponential time. You may find this paper helpful; it describes a polynomial-time approximation algorithm for this problem, as well as a polynomial-time algorithm for cases where the graph has at most degree 4:

> Qiao, Yu. "[Optimal Euler Circuit of Maximum Contiguous Cost](http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~qiao/publish/OEC_IEICE.pdf)." IEICE Trans. Fundamentals E90-A, no. 1 (2007): 274-280.

Answer (score 0):

A good approximation gives the Hilbert Curve.